# How can I select a subset of data from a matrix based on field values in R

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
QUERY_SOURCE    FIELDS_SEARCHED SIMILARITY  MEASURE TOPIC_NUM   VALUE
D   A   bm25    infAP   1   0.008
D   A   bm25    infNDCG 1   0.0776
D   A   bm25    iP10    1   0.1
D   A   bm25    iP50    1   0.08
D   A   bm25    iP100   1   0.06
D   A   bm25    inum_rel_ret    1   6.0001
D   A   bm25    inum_rel    1   109.8145
D   A   bm25    num_ret 1   1000
D   A   bm25    infAP   2   0.0262
```

How can I select a data series into an R DataFrame for specific column values, i.e. I want the 'Value' entries for Query_Source='D',Measure='infAP' for values [1..30] of TOPIC_NUM

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subset` function.

```
# lets say df is your input data frame
subset(df, Query_Source=='D' & Measure=='infAP' & TOPIC_NUM > 1 & TOPIC_NUM < 30)
```

This will directly return you a data frame. Also, you can add as many conditions you like based on your preference.

Comment: Thanks Sandy, can you sort the data as well?

Comment: You can sort using `order` function. `df2<- df[order(yourcolumn),]`.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logical index to subset the 'VALUE' (assuming that the dataset is a `data.frame`)

```
with(df1, VALUE[QUERY_SOURCE == "D" & MEASURE == "infAP" & TOPIC_NUM %in% 1:30])
```

Answer (score 0):

using the dplyr

```
df%>%filter(QUERY_SOURCE == "D" & MEASURE == "infAP" & TOPIC_NUM %in% 1:30)%>%select(VALUE)
```

using the data.table

```
df1[QUERY_SOURCE == "D" & MEASURE == "infAP" & TOPIC_NUM %in% 1:30,VALUE]
```